# In tensorflow 2.0 keras, how can we get gradients for the regularisation parameters like l1 and l2?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

For example if we build a network using

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L1L1(l1=0.1, l2=0.2))
```

You get entries appearing in the `model.losses` however they do not appear to get recalculated when changing l1, and l2. Furthermore, it seems like the loss function is not differentiable w.r.t l1 and l2 even after replace l1, l2 with

```
l1 = tf.keras.backend.variable(name='l1', value=0.1)
l2 = tf.keras.backend.variable(name='l2', value=0.1)
```

The variables *are* trainable via some function that explicitly uses them.

UPDATE:

I have a feeling it is the `_gather_children...` function that has a non-differentiable boolean in it unfortunately.

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in converted code:

<ipython-input-272-b7a1c0374804>:7 train_one  *
    d = loss(x, y)
<ipython-input-222-e2bf7d12dcd8>:10 loss  *
    layer_losses = tf.reduce_mean(agent.predictor.losses)
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1015 losses
    return collected_losses + self._gather_children_attribute('losses')
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2336 _gather_children_attribute
    getattr(layer, attribute) for layer in nested_layers))
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2336 <genexpr>
    getattr(layer, attribute) for layer in nested_layers))
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 losses
    loss_tensor = regularizer()
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1087 _tag_unconditional
    loss = loss()
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1916 _loss_for_variable
    regularization = regularizer(v)
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/regularizers.py:57 __call__
    if not self.l1 and not self.l2:
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:450 __bool__
    return bool(self.read_value())
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:765 __bool__
    self._disallow_bool_casting()
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:531 _disallow_bool_casting
    "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
asdf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:518 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
    " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the code to debug the issue ?

Comment: I dug into this and I don't think it is currently possible to do gradients across the optimizer steps so this question is sort of irrelevant.